# Finding the maximum number of vertex disjoint from source to destination

Tags: graph, max-flow

I am aware that the problem has been discussed here more than once. However, I need to find the maximum number K of vertex-disjoint paths in a directed graph with a running time of |V| x |E|.

I know the algorithm of transforming each vertex into v_in, v_out and adding an edge with capacity 1 from v_in to v_out and for each pair of vertices (u,v) add an edge with capacity 1 from u_out to v_in and then compute the max flow in this network. However, after my calculations this algorithm takes O(E) preprocessing + O(VE^2) or O(V^2E) for max flow. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use James B Orlin's + KRT (King, Rao, Tarjan)'s algorithm instead of Ford Fulkerson to calculate flow and it'll be O(V*E). (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)